# How to make Wordat return the word at that location on the page as a String. And return null if the line or word do not exist

Tags: java, arraylist

Your Page class needs a method called addLine that takes a String parameter that holds a line in the page. This method will be called repeatedly to add lines to the page your class is storing.

You will also need a method named numLines that returns the number of lines on the page.

Lastly, you will need a wordAt method that takes two parameters, a line number and a word number and returns the word at that location on the page as a String. The line number and word number are 1-based indexes for the line on the page and the word on that line. (The first line is line 1, the first word on any line is word 1). Return null if the line or word do not exist.

I've tried 
public String wordAt (int ln, int wn) {
        return line[ln][wn];

This for my main.java

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Page p = new Page();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        p.addLine(s.nextLine());
    }

    System.out.println("Number of lines: " + p.numLines());
    System.out.println("First word: " + p.wordAt(1, 1));
    System.out.println("Another word: " + p.wordAt(15, 5));
    }
    }
```

This is for page.java

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class Page {
    private ArrayList <ArrayList <String>> line;
    public Page () {
    line = new ArrayList <ArrayList<String>>();
    line.add(null);

     }

      public void addLine (String ip) {
      ArrayList<String> enter = new ArrayList<String>();
      String[] arr = ip.split(" ");
      enter.add(null);
      for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      enter.add(arr[i]);
      }
      line.add(enter);

             }

      public int numLines () {
      int totalnum = line.size() - 1;
      return 0;
      }

      public String wordAt (int ln, int wn) {


      }
      }
```

code should return the word at that location on the page as a String. Return null if the line or word do not exist.

Comment: There is a difference between an "array" and a `ArrayList`, they don't have the same syntax for starters.  You need to be using `get` to start with, but remember, Java is mostly `0` indexed, so you will need to compensate for that.  You should also be checking to make sure that the indices are within range

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Page {

    private final List<String> lines;

    public Page() {
        lines = new ArrayList();        
    }

    public String wordAt(int lineIndex, int wordIndex) {
        lineIndex--; // offset before doing anything
        wordIndex--;
        if (lineIndex < numLines() && lineIndex >= 0) {
            String line = lines.get(lineIndex);
            // split words at each space(s) (one or more space characters)
            // assignment didn't specify what a "word" is.
            String[] split = line.split("[ ]+");
            if (wordIndex >= 0 && wordIndex < split.length) {
                return split[wordIndex];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int numLines() {
        return lines.size();
    }

    public boolean addLine(String line) {
        return lines.add(line);
    }

}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Page page = new Page();        
        page.addLine("Will the real slim shady, please stand up");
        page.addLine("... please stand up, please stand up.");        
        System.out.println(page.wordAt(1, 9)); // should be null
        System.out.println(page.wordAt(1, 1)); // should be Will
        System.out.println(page.wordAt(2, 1)); // should be ... (ellipses)
        System.out.println(page.wordAt(2, 3)); // should be ("stand")
        System.out.println(page.wordAt(3, 1)); // no third line... (null)


    }


Output:
run:
null
Will
...
stand
null
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```